# Combine two lists with all possible combinations

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

I have the following lists:

```
list1={1,2,3,4,5};
list2={10,20,30,40,50};
```

I want to combine these lists such that each element in `list1` is added to every element in `list2`, to form `list3` as

```
list3={1+10,1+20,1+30,1+40,1+50,2+10,2+20,2+30,2+40,2+50,....,5+10,5+20,5+30,5+40,5+50}
```

How can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 8):

```
Total[Tuples[{list1, list2}], {2}] (* or *)
Join @@ Outer[Plus, list1, list2]
```

> {11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 14, 24, 
>   34, 44, 54, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55}

```
 Tuples[Inactive[Plus][list1, list2]] (* or *)
 Join @@ Outer[Inactive[Plus], list1, list2]
```

> {1+10, 1+20, 1+30, 1+40, 1+50, 2+10, 2+20, 2+30, 2+40, 2+50, 3+10, 3+20,3+30,3+40, 3+50, 4+10, 4+20, 4+30, 4+40, 4+50, 5+10, 5+20, 5+30, 5+40, 5+50}

Comment: Big lesson @kglr Inactive ... never found before, thanks

Comment: @AnxonPués, it is new in version 10.0

Answer (score 2):

```
Plus @@@ Tuples[{list1, list2}]
```

or

```
Flatten @ Outer[Plus, list1, list2]
```

> {11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 14, 24,
>   34, 44, 54, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55}

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to have as indicated this would work

```
Flatten[Table[
  ToString[list1[[i]]] <> "+" <> ToString[list2[[j]]], {i, 
   Length[list1]}, {j, Length[list2]}]]
```